# Not enough disk space to unzip 50 GB file on Ubuntu 16.04: Can I extract and reduce zip file size at the same time?

Tags: hard-drive, zip, 7-zip, gzip

I have a 50 GB zip file, which contains roughly 50.000 jpg images. The jpgs are, unzipped, around 55 GB. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

But I only have 70 GB disk size on that system. So I get a disk error in the middle of the unzipping.

Can I unzip the file, and at the same time reduce the zip file size (e.g. delete the data of the jpgs which have already been unzipped), so that all fits on my disk?

--- Same question for Windows exists ---

Someone had the exact same question for Windows: [unzip file on small drive](https://superuser.com/questions/613034/unzip-file-on-small-drive)

The proposed solutions there do unfortunately not solve the problem for me on Linux (and neither seem to solve the problem well on Windows). So I am keeping this question, in case there is a good solution for Linux. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the link. My question is exactly the same, except that I am looking at Ubuntu instead of Windows. The answers there don't work for me (and didn't solve the problem for Windows that well either). Should I close this thread and ask a follow-up question there? Or keep this one, since there may be Ubuntu specific solutions that work? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Keep this one, unless somebody finds a duplicate with Linux solution. For now keep the question. "Follow-up question there" doesn't fit our Q&A model; you shouldn't ask similar questions neither in comments nor in "answers".

Comment: Just keep this one. Maybe [edit] it to say that you have looked at the other question and that it doesn’t help you. Sorry for marking your question as a dup without reading it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNOME's built-in `Archive Manager` to open the zip file without extracting. Once you've opened it you can copy ~10-15 GB of files to the folder you want them extracted to, and then delete them from the archive. Rinse and repeat.

There are multiple utilities which have this functionality (Archive-Mounter, [archivemount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/archivemount.1.html), [GVFS](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs), [AVFS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=avfs)) but Archive Manager has a very convenient GUI and will probably be the easiest to use.

Alternatively, you could attach an external drive and use it as temporary storage.

Side note: Windows has the ability to mount zip files like this built-in, I'm surprised no one pointed this out in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take advantage of the Linux-specific system call [fallocate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html), or the command line equivalent. The `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` mode allows you to zero-out any given part of a file, and where possible the affected blocks are released back to the filesystem, making a *sparse* file.

Not all filesystems support this call, but ext4 does.

The idea is that you extract a file from the archive, then use fallocate to zero out the part of the archive that it occupied. The dictionary of the zip archive holds the offset to the start of each file's header, and the compressed length of the file within the archive.

As an example of the concept here's a minimal Python3 script to extract and do the system call
on each file.  You should not use it without careful
testing. You might be able to do the same in a shell script, if you
can extract the information. fallocate was not in a standard Python library
for me, so the first half of the script uses ctypes to call it. The script
needs the python zipfile library.  It may also need other changes for your
system. The amount to zero-out does not include the size of the header, which stops them becoming one contiguous area.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# https://superuser.com/a/1371106/458747
# int fallocate(int fd, int mode, off_t offset, off_t len)
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
fallocate = libc.fallocate
fallocate.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_longlong, ctypes.c_longlong)
FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE = 2
FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE = 1

import sys, subprocess, zipfile  # will need zlib for compression
myzip = sys.argv[1]
fd = open(myzip,"r+")
fno = fd.fileno()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(myzip, 'r')
for info in zf.infolist():
   zf.extract(info)
   # print(info.header_offset,info.compress_size)
   rc = fallocate(fno, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE|FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE,
                  info.header_offset, info.compress_size)
   if rc!=0: print("fallocate failed\n")
   subprocess.call("ls -ls "+myzip,shell=True)
```

I tested it on a simple zip archive and you can see in the first column the number of blocks being used by the archive reducing as each file is extracted:

```
24224 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
23292 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
22524 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
21524 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
...
2800 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
1868 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
880 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
124 -rw-r--r--  25562742 Oct 29 22:56 ../my.zip
```